# NetBeans: change autocomplete attributes from single to double quotes

Tags: html, netbeans, formatting, editor, double-quotes

NB started to put single quotes around my attributes when editing HTML instead of double quotes... up until yesterday it worked just fine... and it is really annoying now... I've must have pressed or do something unintentionally and now I don't know where to change it back...

please help

just to be clear of what I am talking about when editing a html document, when I type:

```
<input type=
```

after typing =, NB puts '' automatically after, instead of "" as it did before.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should uncheck "Smart Quotes Completion" in

Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion